# Erros de sintaxe em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, passagem-por-referência, passagem-por-valor

Estou fazendo este exercício em C, mas travei nessa parte de passagem de parâmetros com ponteiro.

Basicamente o programa abaixo soma a parcela de números reais e números inteiros.

O problema é que os resultados atuais são:

**a = 12 (correto!)**

**b = 10 (Errado!)**

O resultado de B está incorreto e estou quebrando a cabeça tentando entender o porque...

#### DETALHE IMPORTANTE!

Conforme fala o exercício, EU NÃO POSSO ALTERAR O MAIN

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Complexo {
  int real;
  int imaginario;
};

struct Complexo insereComplexo(int r, int i){
  struct Complexo novo;
  novo.real = r;
  novo.imaginario = i;
  return novo;
}

void somaComplexo(struct Complexo *a, struct Complexo b){
  a->real += b.real;
  a->imaginario += b.imaginario;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  struct Complexo a, b;
  a = insereComplexo(4,7);
  b = insereComplexo(8,10);
  somaComplexo(&a, b);
  printf("%d\n", a.real);
  printf("%d\n", b.imaginario);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: em vez de `printf("%d\n", b.imaginario);`, não deveria ser `printf("%d\n", a.imaginario);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Complexo {
  int real;
  int imaginario;
};

struct Complexo insereComplexo(int r, int i){
  struct Complexo novo;
  novo.real = r;
  novo.imaginario = i;
  return novo;
}

void somaComplexo(struct Complexo *a, struct Complexo b){
  a->real += b.real;
  a->imaginario += b.imaginario;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  struct Complexo a, b;
  a = insereComplexo(4,7);
  b = insereComplexo(8,10);
  somaComplexo(&a, b);
  printf("%d\n", a.real);
  printf("%d\n", a.imaginario);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1FMIMu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ehwsckpx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Complex.c).

Portando parece ser erro de digitação, já que está acumulando os valores em `a`, e imprime o real de `a`, mas o imaginário imprime de `b` que não está acumulando nada.

Provavelmente eu teria feito retornar `Complexo` e não usaria ponteiro.

Comment: Nossa.... estava quebrando a cabeça por um erro bobo de digitação haha MUITO obrigado mesmo Maniero!